# Removing Accept in the response header of Spring Boot WS web service

Tags: spring-boot, soapui, spring-ws

How I can remove Accept from response HTTP header of Soap web service developed in String Boot. I'm building web service from the WSDL file.

```
@Bean(name = "testwebservice")
public SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition() {
    SimpleWsdl11Definition s = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
    s.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("xsd/test.wsdl"));
    return s;
}
```

[image]
[image]

When we consume that Soap web service in the client application below logs created against the request.

```
10.0.10.17 - - [02/Jul/2020:12:07:19 +0500] "POST /ws/test null" 400 1893
```

Answer (score 0):

Accept is request header, web service response simply could not send that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept

Obviously this view displays Accept header of request.

Comment: We have receiving Accept in the response HTTP header and facing issue to consume web service in that case.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama How do you see that? Have you checked actually sent headers with a tool like wireshark? Really hard to beleive spring boot could behave like that out of the box...

Comment: I'm testing web service from SoapUI-5.5.0.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama I'm quite sure that the displayed is Accept header sent in request. What is the issue with consuming the service? You have posted nothing about it.

Comment: I am sending any request header and also updated the question with request header and error logs during consuming web service.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama do you know what does this log mean? What is "null" and what "400" stands for? But anyway, your call from SoapUI is successful, as soon as 200 was returned. It means that you need to dig into client application to find what it does wrong.

Comment: Client application owner suggest to remove Accept from the response HTTP header. Please guide the solution to remove Accept in the response header.